# Android google map invalid provider: null

Tags: android, google-maps

I don't know why my code always gives a null provider i tried many solution but always theres is  two case if the error disappear it won't add in database and if it add there an error in application lunch.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,      LocationListener {
private TextView userName, userEmail;
private CircleImageView userImageView;
private String TAG = "MainActivity";
Location mLastLocation;
double latitude, longitude;
private PositionData positionData;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
private String uid;
int count = 0;



 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference =    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    this.setTitle("Couverture 4G");
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        uid = user.getUid();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    // View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
    userName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userNameDrawer);
    userEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userEmailDrawer);
    userImageView = (CircleImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.userImageViewDrawer);
    // FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
        String namee = user.getDisplayName();
        String emaile = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
        // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
        // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
        String uid = user.getUid();
        Log.d(TAG, "uid = " + uid + " name = " + namee + " email = " + emaile);
        userEmail.setText(emaile);
        userName.setText(namee);
        if (photoUrl != null)
            Glide.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(userImageView);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        // Getting longitude of the current location
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        Log.d("TAG MAPS", "lat = " + latitude + "long = " + longitude);
        this.onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    FragmentTransaction ftt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_activity_container, new ClimatFragment()).addToBackStack(null);
    ftt.commit();

}
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        if (count == 1) {
            count = 0;

            moveTaskToBack(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tapez sur le Bouton Retour une seconde fois pour quitter.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            count++;
        }


    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
        // Handle the camera action
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_speedtest) {
        FragmentTransaction ftt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_activity_container, new SpeedTestFragment()).addToBackStack(null);
        ftt.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_climat) {


        FragmentTransaction ftt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_activity_container, new ClimatFragment()).addToBackStack(null);
        ftt.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_chat) {
        FragmentTransaction ftt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_activity_container, new ChatFragment()).addToBackStack(null);
        ftt.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    positionData = new PositionData();
    positionData.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    positionData.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
    positionData.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    MyUtils myUtils = new MyUtils();
    positionData.setNetworkType(myUtils.getNetworkClass(this));

    Log.d(TAG, "Changed");
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("positions").child(uid).child("" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000).setValue(positionData);
}
  }
```

my log Error

```
   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.esprit.couverture4g/com.esprit.couverture4g.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                     at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1704)
                     at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1194)
                     at com.esprit.couverture4g.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.esprit.couverture4g, PID: 29830
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.esprit.couverture4g/com.esprit.couverture4g.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                  at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1704)
                  at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1194)
                  at com.esprit.couverture4g.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post your error log as well

Comment: Check my update junaid hafeez